# Using lists to change columns in multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

I am using a list of variables to download and create dataframes in R. I'd like to be able to use this list to make changes to different columns in each dataframe, but I am having trouble calling particular columns using the list of variables.

```
countries= c("USA","CHN")

for (i in 1:length(countries)){
    download.file(url[i],savedata[i])
    assign(countries[i],xmlToDataFrame(savedata[i]))
}
```

Now I have dataframes that look like this:

```
head(USA)
        indicator       country date          value decimal
1 GDP (current US$) United States 2012 15684800000000       0
2 GDP (current US$) United States 2011 14991300000000       0
3 GDP (current US$) United States 2010 14419400000000       0
4 GDP (current US$) United States 2009 13898300000000       0
5 GDP (current US$) United States 2008 14219300000000       0
6 GDP (current US$) United States 2007 13961800000000       0
```

And I would like to go through and make several changes, such as formatting the date column with the `as.date()` function, or changing the units of the value column, but I want to be able to do the same to both dataframe (or an arbitrary number in case I increase the length of countries.

However, whenever I try to do this I can seem to use the list of countries in the countries variable to get 'inside' each data frame. My initial guess was putting something like this in a loop:

```
assign(paste(countries[i],"date",sep="$"),
    as.date(get(paste(countries[i],"date",sep="$")))
```

In particular, I get confused about how the `get(paste(countries[i]))` works if I am not trying to get the particular column date, and how the `paste(countries[i],"date",sep="$")` prints the correct name, but I can't seem to get just the one column I'd like to manipulate.

Additionally, I realize loops are not the ideal way of doing this, but I've been having the same problem with the apply functions, though I am likely having trouble with them due to my lack of experience. Suggestions for either how to do it in a loop, or with out, would be much appreciated. Super R novice here, just trying to learn. Also, if you've come across a clear explanation/answer for this somewhere else, I'd appreciate you pointing me towards it.

Comment: You might find it easier to flatten the structure and put all data in a single data.frame. Using the list of data frames from @Ferdinand answer's below you can stack them all in a dataframe with the command `Reduce(rbind, mylist)`. Once you have one data frame only, formatting operations become much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier if you use lists. Start with an empty one:

```
mylist = list()
```

Then change this:

```
assign(countries[i],xmlToDataFrame(savedata[i]))
```

to this:

```
mylist[[i]] <- xmlToDataFrame(savedata[i])
```

Then make a function that does your formatting, for instance:

```
f <- function(df){
    within(df, date <- as.date(date))
}
```

And use `lapply` to apply it to all dataframes:

```
mylist2 <- lapply(mylist, f)
```

If you want to access dataframes by name, use this:

```
names(mylist2) <- countries
```

And test:

```
mylist2[["USA"]]
```

Comment: That was very helpful and informative, both in understanding how to use lists and apply functions, as well as bringing my attention to the within function. Thought I was having some trouble in the end with it, but it was my own confusion, this worked well and was educational. Thank you.