# How to select and apply a function to multiple column within a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I am using a list of two dataframes that share several similar columns, and I want to be able to convert the class of several columns in each dataframe in one shot using their column names and not the column position.

I’ve searched StockOverflow and found similar questions here: here:[Using lists to change columns in multiple dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434723/using-lists-to-change-columns-in-multiple-dataframes-in-r) and here: [applying a function for a list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954538/applying-a-function-for-a-list-of-dataframes).  However, I am stuck trying to use multiple column names to convert the dates.
Here is a sample data to illustrate my problem:

```
df1 <- data.frame("t1" = c(20070103, 20070104, 20070105, 20070108, 20070109), "t2" = c(20070110,20070111, 20070112, 20070113, 20070114), A = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame("t1" = c(20080103, 20080104, 20080105, 20080108, 20080109), "t2" = c(20080110,20080111, 20080112, 20080113, 20080114), B = 1:5)
l <- list(df1 = df1, df2=df2)
```

So far I’ve found two solutions which I can repeat for every column I want to convert to a date:

```
#1
l2 <-lapply(l, function(x) transform(x, t1 = as.Date(as.character(t1), "%Y%m%d")))

#2
f <- function(df){
    within(df, t1 <- as.date(date))
}
l2 <- lapply(l, f)
```

However, is there way I can use either method to get multiple columns (not the entire dataframe or list) in one shot and by using column names? I’ve tried the following codes to no avail:

```
periods <- c( "t1", "t2" )
ls2 <-lapply(ls, function(x) transform(x, periods = as.Date(as.character(periods), "%Y%m%d")) 

f <- function(df) {
     within(df, t1 <- as.Date(as.character(t1), "%Y%m%d"))
     within(df, t2 <- as.Date(as.character(t2), "%Y%m%d"))
         }
l2 <- lapply(l, f)

for (i in periods)
    l2 <-lapply(l, function(x) transform(x, i = as.Date(as.character(i), "%Y%m%d")))
```

Comment: This is quite easy.  How do you want to programmatically identify your columns?

Comment: You also have a fundamental misunderstanding of the apply concept that we can help with.

Comment: I'm new to R, so I'm not sure if I'm answering your question, but I would l like to just specify the names of the columns I would like to convert into dates.  Would I be able to use the character vector, 'periods', in my function or by using lapply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Suggestion #1, simple:

  ```
  lapply(l, function(dfrm, periods, fmt) {
      for (ff in which(colnames(dfrm) %in% periods))
          dfrm[,ff] <- as.Date(as.character(dfrm[,ff]), fmt)
      dfrm
  }, periods=c('t1', 't2'), fmt='%Y%m%d')
  ```

  Using `ff in which(...)` allows us to specify column headers that
  may or may not be included, no change done if some or all of them
  are vacant in a specific data.frame.

  The second and third arguments to lapply, `periods=c('t1','t2')`,
  allows you to specify the format and column names and (cleanly)
  bring them into the inner loops (without having the inside of the
  loops reach outside for data, something that will bite you if/when
  you copy/paste code into a different project).
- Suggestion #2, try to convert all columns:

  ```
  lapply(l, function(dfrm, fmt) {
      for (cc in seq.int(ncol(dfrm)))
          if (! is.na(as.Date(as.character(dfrm[1,cc]), format=fmt)))
              dfrm[,cc] <- as.Date(as.character(dfrm[,cc]), format=fmt)
      dfrm
  }, fmt='%Y%m%d')
  ```

  This can fail if you have other columns that *could* be inferred
  as dates (using these heuristics) but aren't intended as such.

  I limit the check to the first row for performance, in case large
  amounts of data would cause this to be a performance bottleneck.
- Suggestion #3, same thing, but more robust to false-alarms:

  ```
  lapply(l, function(dfrm, fmt) {
      for (cc in seq.int(ncol(dfrm))) {
          tmp <- as.Date(as.character(dfrm[,cc]), format=fmt)
          if (! any(is.na(tmp))) dfrm[,cc] <- tmp
      }
      dfrm
  }, fmt='%Y%m%d')
  ```

  Alright, we've reduced the number of false-alarms by checking to
  make certain *all* values converted to a date, but this means that
  if any one cell fails in an otherwise valid column of dates, then
  the whole column suffers. You can get around this perhaps by
  checking the number of percentage of fails, but now we're getting
  a bit ridiculous ...
- Suggestion #4, using regular expressions on the column names:

  ```
  lapply(l, function(dfrm, regex, fmt) {
      for (cc in grep(regex, colnames(dfrm)))
          dfrm[,cc] <- as.Date(as.character(dfrm[,cc]), format=fmt)
      dfrm
  }, regex='^t[0-9]+$', fmt='%Y%m%d')
  ```

  This may spark other questions if you aren't comfortable with
  regular expressions.

These could have been done with a nested `*apply` instead of a `for`
loop, but since R is now performing quite well with loops like this, I
don't think it's a big concern. (It will depend on the size of your
data.)

If you're more comfortable with the naming convention for the column
headers, then #4 might be your answer. If not (or you aren't
comfortable with regular expressions) but you are confident that the
non-date columns will not be mis-construed, then #2 or #3 work well, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
l.new <- lapply(l, function(x) {x[periods] <- lapply(x[periods], as.character); x})
str(l.new)
```

produces

```
List of 2
 $ df1:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ t1: chr [1:5] "20070103" "20070104" "20070105" "20070108" ...
  ..$ t2: chr [1:5] "20070110" "20070111" "20070112" "20070113" ...
  ..$ A : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ df2:'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ t1: chr [1:5] "20080103" "20080104" "20080105" "20080108" ...
  ..$ t2: chr [1:5] "20080110" "20080111" "20080112" "20080113" ...
  ..$ B : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

UPDATE: In order to get the dates, you can use:

```
lapply(
  l, 
  function(x) {
    x[periods] <- lapply(x[periods], function(x) as.Date(as.character(x), format="%Y%m%d")); 
    x
} )
```

Comment: BrodieG, the code seems to break down when I use as.Date in place of as.character after I run your original code.  Where in the code can I specify a non standard unambiguous format if I'm using as.Date?  Ex: l.new <- lapply(l.new, function(x) {x[periods] <- lapply(x[periods], as.Date); x})

Comment: @Hakeem82, it breaks down because your dates are not in standard unambiguous format (yyyy-mm-dd).  You can tell `as.Date` what format they are in with the `format` argument.  See update.